# Check if a child element does not have a specific class?

Tags: javascript, css, class, children, getelementsbyclassname

I am trying to find if a child element does not have a specific class.

My elements are as follows:

```
<g id="note1">
    <path id="Barline1" d="M55.837,19.278h0.249c0.11,0,0.199,0.089,0.199,0.199V40.56c0,0.11-0.089,0.199-0.199,0.199h-0.249c-0.11,0-0.199-0.089-0.199-0.199V19.478C55.638,19.368,55.727,19.278,55.837,19.278z"/>
    <path class="root" d="M54.113,38.945c1.116,0,2.172,0.578,2.172,1.813c0,1.435-1.116,2.411-2.052,2.969c-0.717,0.418-1.514,0.717-2.331,0.717c-1.116,0-2.172-0.578-2.172-1.813c0-1.435,1.116-2.411,2.052-2.969C52.499,39.244,53.296,38.945,54.113,38.945z"/>
</g>
<g id="note2">
    <path id="BarLine2" d="M70.852,16.788h0.249c0.11,0,0.199,0.089,0.199,0.199v21.082c0,0.11-0.089,0.199-0.199,0.199h-0.249c-0.11,0-0.199-0.089-0.199-0.199V16.987C70.653,16.877,70.742,16.788,70.852,16.788z"/>
    <path class="root" d="M69.127,36.454c1.116,0,2.172,0.578,2.172,1.813c0,1.435-1.116,2.411-2.052,2.969c-0.717,0.418-1.514,0.717-2.331,0.717c-1.116,0-2.172-0.578-2.172-1.813c0-1.435,1.116-2.411,2.052-2.969C67.513,36.753,68.31,36.454,69.127,36.454z"/>
    <path class="interval third" d="M69.127,31.473c1.116,0,2.172,0.578,2.172,1.813c0,1.435-1.116,2.411-2.052,2.969c-0.717,0.418-1.514,0.717-2.331,0.717c-1.116,0-2.172-0.578-2.172-1.813c0-1.435,1.116-2.411,2.052-2.969C67.513,31.772,68.31,31.473,69.127,31.473z"/>
</g>
```

The `g` element with `id="note1"` does not have any child elements with `class="interval"`. The `g` element with `id="note2"` does.  I'm trying to use the following javascript to determine if an element **does not** have a child element with `class="interval"`:

```
for(var n=0;n<document.getElementsByClassName('root').length;n++){
    if(document.getElementById('note'+(n+1)).getElementsByClassName('interval') ){
          //some child element has class
     } else {
          //no child element has class
     }
}
```

I'm getting the error message that the property or method `document.getElementsByClassName` is not supported on both `g` elements.

According to [this example](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/document.getElementsByClassName), the code should return all the elements with the class I want which are under the element of the id I specified.  Any ideas on what I am doing wrong or what alternatives I might try?

Comment: Is there some reason you're starting from the `.root` elements and not the `note_` elements?

Comment: probably ignorance.  I'm pretty new to all this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [element.querySelectorAll()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document.querySelectorAll) :

```
 if(document.getElementById('note'+(n+1)).querySelectorAll('.interval').length > 0){
     /*There are elements with CSS class 'interval'*/
 }
 else{
     /*There are no elements with CSS class 'interval'*/
 }
```

Comment: This worked great for checking if a child element did not have a class element.  Though, I'm not sure how to access the child element now when it does have the class.  Is it `document.getElementById('note'+(n+1)).querySelectorAll('#interval')[0]`  Or once I'm in, do I go back to the `getElementsByClassName`?

Comment: @ChristopherGaston : You can access elements with this class through iterating the NodeList `document.getElementById('note'+(n+1)).querySelectorAll('#interval')` .And use,the first one you can access the way you did it in the comment.

Comment: Worked great.  You may want to edit your code.  You put down #interval which is id selector and it should actually be .interval for class selector.